# Excel: Search for a cell address, then use that address in a function

Tags: excel, search, if-statement, contains

I'm having some trouble with a rather convoluted Excel issue, but I think I have my problem figured out.

Lets use successful pets as an example. We have three pets, a cat, a dog, and a bird. The cat and bird were both successful at jumping through a hoop, but the dog wasn't. I have those results listed in one table:

Sheet1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWdJd.jpg

I also have another table which lists my pets:

Sheet2: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aN50o.jpg

In Sheet2 B2, I would like to have a formula that will return the word "Success." I can't seem to get a function to work for this.

The logical progression that I see is to first identify which cell holds the word "Cat" in Sheet1. Then I would need to set up an if statement searching for the word Success in that cell.

I have the second part down: =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("successful",Sheet1!A1)), "Success", "Fail")

What I need to do now is write something that will search out and populate the "Sheet1!A1" portion of the above function by searching Sheet1 column A for the value in Sheet2 cell A2. Can anyone help with this or get me pointed in the right direction?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have to search within the contents of a cell to determine if it was met or can your data be arranged in a different way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote it down a bit quickly, so there might be something shorter ^^;

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Successful",VLOOKUP("*"&A1&"*",Sheet1!A:A,1,0))),"Success","Fail")
```

The innermost function is `VLOOKUP` and will look for the corresponding cell in Sheet1 containing 'dog' (case insensitive). It will return the value `The dog failed`.

Now, the next formula is `SEARCH` (a case insensitive version of `FIND`) and will look for `Successful`. The rest should be relatively easy to understand :)

Comment: ...an alternative is to use COUNTIFS to search for rows which contain both the animal and "Success", i.e. `=IF(COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A:A,"*"&A1&"*",Sheet1!A:A,"*success*"),"Success","Fail")` - that could conceivably give different results to VLOOKUP if the animal appears in more than one row.....

Comment: @barryhoudini Indeed! Except we'll have another problem; not with the result but with the data. In which case, OP will have to choose which result is the correct one, unless failures can be ignored if there's one success. Yup, sounds good!